# How to remove the comma in the output?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
     int  a[8]={500,100,50,20,10,5,2,1},m,temp,i; 
     scanf("%d",&m);

     temp=m;

     for(i=0;i<8;i++)
     {
         printf("%d:%d, ",a[i],temp/a[i]);
         temp=temp%a[i];
     }
}
```

When i try to get output, after the last digit also there is comma. How do I fix that ?

Comment: you can use sprintf instead of printf and delete from the buffer of sprint f before sending it to the output stream (stout). posting an answer.

Comment: printf("\b ");at end of main

Comment: print all (n-1) items in the way that you have printed then print the last item outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to before end of main(), Here '\b' will move insertion point to back and space overwrites the previous value (This is only valid for screen)

```
printf("\b\b ");
```

OR

```
printf("%d:%d",a[i],temp/a[i]);
 if( (i+1) < 8)
     printf(", ");
```

OR

```
 printf("%d:%d",a[0],temp/a[0]);
 for(i=1;i<8;i++)
 {
     printf(", ");
     printf("%d:%d",a[i],temp/a[i]);
     temp=temp%a[i];
 }
```

Comment: Only, possibly, when output goes to the screen. If output goes to a file, a printer, a device driver for the Rover Explorer, ... this *hack* will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can print a comma before each item except the first:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     if (i > 0) printf(", ");    // print comma between items

     printf("%d:%d", a[i], temp / a[i]);
     temp = temp % a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main() 
{
    char buffer[1024]; //lets assume that 1024 is enough. 
    int  a[8]={500,100,50,20,10,5,2,1},m,temp,i; 
    scanf("%d",&m);
    temp=m;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
     sprintf(buffer+strlen(buffer)-1,"%d:%d, ",a[i],temp/a[i]);
     temp=temp%a[i];
     }
     buffer[strlen(buffer)-2]='\0'; // why -2? because we need to delete the space and comma from the string end
     printf("%s",buffer);

}
```

## another way to solve, more effecient (with sprintf return value without strlen) see below

```
int main() 
{
    char buffer[1024]; //lets assume that 1024 is enough. 
    int  a[8]={500,100,50,20,10,5,2,1},m,temp,i,count=0; 
    scanf("%d",&m);
    temp=m;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
     count=sprintf(buffer+count-1,"%d:%d, ",a[i],temp/a[i]);
     temp=temp%a[i];
     }
     buffer[count-3]='\0'; // why -3? because we need to delete the space comma and \0 from the string end
     printf("%s",buffer);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there will always be one item at least, what I like to do is make the first print special (no comma) and all subsequent prints with the same format, so "unroll" the first pass and do `n - 1` passes.

It's a micro (nano/pico/femto/atto) -optimization, but there's no `if` inside the loop

```
//  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//      printf("%d, ", i);
//  }
    printf("0");
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        printf(", %d", i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there something you don't need to print under certain conditions? Check those conditions and don't print it if they are  true.

In your case you need to append `", "` after all items except the last. There are several ways to do it. The simplier one is

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    printf("%d:%d",a[i],temp/a[i]);
    temp=temp%a[i];

    if ( i != 7 )
    {
        printf(", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        const char *end = i + 1 < 8 ? ", " : "\n";
        printf ("%d:%d%s", a[i], temp/a[i], end);
        temp = temp % a[i];
    }
```

In the last iteration, this will add the new line character (`\n`), instead of comma(`,`), at the end of output.
In case if you don't want new line character (`\n`) at the end of output, just replace `"\n"` with empty string `""` in the ternary operator expression.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int  a[8]={500,100,50,20,10,5,2,1},m,temp,i; 
    scanf("%d",&m);
    temp=m;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        printf("%d:%d%s",a[i],temp/a[i],i == 7 ? "": ", ");
        temp=temp%a[i];
    }
}
```